# In what condition i can use solr core in phalcon?

Tags: phalcon

I have make library for solr data but it's not working with phalcon framwork

Getting error : SolrClient' class not found

if i can use core php then it's working proper.

Comment: please add in your code as well so we can see where the issue is

Comment: [Please, read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)